# auth.log内のAcceptedのログのfromをチェックしたい

Tags: shellscript

万一、サーバーに不正ログインがあった場合のため、
1日１回、auth.log内のAcceptedのログのアクセス先、from xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx をチェックし、別途登録した
アドレス以外からのログインが有った場合には、メールを送ることを、シェルスクリプトで書けないでしょうか？

よろしく、お願いします。

Comment: 明確な回答をするためにはauth.logの形式がわからないと、難しいと思います。ログの形式も合わせて記述してください。

Comment: シェルスクリプトではありませんが、Linux には `auditd` というシステム監査用のコンポーネントが提供されています。参考:[第6章 システム監査 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-jp/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing) 利用例として [How To Track Successful And Failed Login Attempts In Linux](https://www.2daygeek.com/check-track-successful-failed-login-attempts-linux/) が参考になるかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

できると思います。

auth.logからAcceptedを含む行を抽出し、許容するアドレスを列挙したsafe.listを使って、許容するアドレスを含まないものに絞り込みます。
結果を変数safe.listに格納しておき、あとは変数${safe.list}の内容をメール送信します。
実用にはもう少し厳密に行抽出をした方がよいと思いますが、考え方は使えると思います。

```
unsafe=$(cat auth.log | grep -E 'Accepted' | grep -v -f safe.list)
```